# Rating bar stretched tablerow height

Tags: android, tablelayout, ratingbar

How can I align the height of last row where I have ratingBar? As you can see the height is larger than the other rows. I tried making marginTop/paddingTop=0, but nothing is working. Is it because I used height=0 and weight = 1 for all rows?

Thanks

[image]

CODE:

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".AddEntry" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr14"
        android:padding="2.5dp"
        android:background="@color/col2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/l_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/comment" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/definputtext2" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr14a"
        android:padding="2.5dp"
        android:background="@color/col1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lab_isdn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/isdn" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/isdn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/definputtext2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr15"
        android:paddingLeft="2.5dp"
        android:background="@color/col2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lab_rating"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rating" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1"
            android:rating="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: No..its not....What is your parent layout ??post full xml... here

Comment: shouldn't it be just `android:layout_height="match_parent"` with `android:layout_weight="1"` ?

Comment: Updated (I omit some middle tablerows, as they have exactly same structure) @Piyush Gupta

Comment: Well, I read in several articles that good practice is to make 0dp, instead of other .. anyway, I tried with match_parent, but no change .. @grexter89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#ff0000"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".AddEntry" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2.5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/l_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Comment" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr14a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2.5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lab_isdn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ISDN" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/isdn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="2.5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lab_rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rating" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="1"
            android:stepSize="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks, it works .. but any particular reason for that? why weight=1 was not giving similar height to each row?

Comment: I have checked that after removing rating bar it display same as other row...with weight = 1...But after add row..it was expanded...so for that reason third row was expanded...and after given 0.7 weight then it is worked.. and this is the reason may be becuase of height of rating bar

Comment: yaa, I noticed as well that if I remove ratingBar, the height is similar to others .. but it is not height issue of ratingBar, coz if you select ratingBar, u will see there are significant margins top & bottom, inside the row!! ... anyway, it works, that's a good thing.. thanks ...